# Члены std::string

Tags: c++

Всегда интересовало, что такое _Ax, _Elem, _Traits.
Есть ли в сети где-нибудь подробное руководство, описывающее все члены класса string (basic_string), или может книга какая-нибудь хорошая?
Очень интересует устройство данного объекта и назначение его переменных, в частности (не только вышеперечисленных).
Вот еще список членов, назначение которых интересует:

```
typedef basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax> _Myt;
typedef _String_val<_Elem, _Ax> _Mybase;
typedef typename _Mybase::_Alty _Alloc;
typedef typename _Alloc::size_type size_type;
typedef typename _Alloc::difference_type _Dift;
typedef _Dift difference_type;
typedef typename _Alloc::pointer _Tptr;
typedef typename _Alloc::const_pointer _Ctptr;
typedef _Tptr pointer;
typedef _Ctptr const_pointer;
typedef typename _Alloc::reference _Reft;
typedef _Reft reference;
typedef typename _Alloc::const_reference const_reference;
typedef typename _Alloc::value_type value_type;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Это не члены класса, а параметры шаблона `template <typename _Elem, typename _Traits, typename _Ax> basic_string` в реализации от `Microsoft`.

> Первый, соответственно, кодирует тип одиночного элемента строки, второй устанавливает специфические `traits` *(то есть некоторые особенности и набор стандартных операций, присущих данному шаблону),* а третий говорит, что мы будем использовать вот такой вот аллокатор для проведения операций с данной специализацией шаблона `basic_string`.

- Насчет `traits,` поскольку это, на мой взгляд, самое интересное - рекомендую ознакомиться с шаблоном под названием [`char_traits.`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/)
- Если вы не знаете, что такое шаблоны в `C++` или плохо их понимаете, то сходу понять принципы их специализации и паттерн [`Template Traits`](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#traits) может быть проблематично.

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понимаю только в чем отличие между template specialization и template instantiation, а так вроде проблем с пониманием шаблонов нет.

Comment: Тогда, думаю, что проблемы с пониманием все-таки есть :)

Comment: @stremm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates

Answer (score 0):

Книга есть. Называется ["Расширение библиотеки STL"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3991940/). Её написал Мэтью Уилсон - один из топовых плюсовиков. Он работает с языком на уровне Герба Саттера и Александреску. Но его книга, разумеется, не только и даже не столько про std::string, сколько про STL вообще. Хотя тема traits там, конечно же, раскрыта полностью.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, литературы много есть на эту тему. На мой взгляд, заслуживает внимания книга Николая Джосьютиса "C++ Стандартная Библиотека", в которой в деталях рассмотрена std::string, а также библиотека STL. Если вы хотите серьезно разобраться в стандартных средствах языка C++, очень вам советую ее прочитать.